# Strange dismissViewControllerAnimated Crash - iOS 8

Tags: objective-c

My app is crashing, only in iOS 8.4, when I try to `dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO`, just after an alert with an `UITextField`.

Changing to animated `YES` it's working well, but I guess that's the not properly fix.

---

Code: (`UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` Modal)

```
- (IBAction)openAlertWithTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Type a number:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Confirm", nil];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    [alertTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    [alertTextField setDelegate:self];
    [alert show];
}

#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Crash
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

        // No Crash
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

---

Crash Log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1981c7bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x18b29c9dc -[UITextField _shouldEndEditing] + 84
2  UIKit                          0x18b21ac70 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 84
3  UIKit                          0x18b29c8bc -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 124
4  UIKit                          0x18b29395c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree] + 208
5  UIKit                          0x18b43effc __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 96
6  UIKit                          0x18b16ac48 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 108
7  UIKit                          0x18b47a94c __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke504 + 364
8  UIKit                          0x18b476784 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 112
9  UIKit                          0x18b4790c0 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 168
10 UIKit                          0x18b292f64 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 132
11 UIKit                          0x18b1a8708 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 408
12 UIKit                          0x18b1a8270 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 188
13 UIKit                          0x18b1a8178 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 104
14 QuartzCore                     0x18aab162c CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 296
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x198831954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x19883620c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1866af7f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1866ad8a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1865d92d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
20 GraphicsServices               0x18feef6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
21 UIKit                          0x18b1d6f40 UIApplicationMain + 1488
22 Get In Manager                 0x10006320c main (main.m:16)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x19885ea08 start + 4
```

Zoombie:

```
2016-05-25 03:02:26.699 App[75590:5686413] *** -[MyUIViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7ff1a2f7a7f0
```

Comment: don't use `UIAlertView` in iOS8+, it is deprecated; use `UIAlertController`,  instead, maybe. if you need to support prior iOS8 versions, you need to shim it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it too early and should try doing in this:

```
- alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

Answer (score 0):

you are use UIAlertview that any button click that automatic dismiss view.

you are doesn't dismiss view that recall of UIAlertview method show. for example:

```
[alertview show];
```